# Exporting shapefile to PostGIS database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, export

How do I export a vector shapefile to PostGIS database? I am asking what format I have to export it.

Comment: You could use the shp2pgsql tool, included in postgis. See http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage

Comment: PostGIS database can import from a shapefile. are you asking how to export from some application in a format other than shapefile?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @oyvind suggested, [shp2pgsql](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg) is the best method for just getting the data into a PostGIS database.  OpenGEO has a good [startup guide](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/shp2pgsql.html) for loading data into PostGIS that should get you up and running if you're having issues.  As @nathanw pointed out, [DB Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html) is a good option for importing a shapefile into a database.  Also available is [PostGIS Manager](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/postgis_manager/), which is a great option if you're working specifically with PostGIS.  @underdark has a [great blog post](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/postgis%20manager/) about how to use it.

You'll need the database connection information (username, hostname or host address, and database name) as well as the SRID for the shapefile, but that is all covered in the OpenGEO startup guide.  Good luck!

Comment: DB Manger supports importing any layer that is open in QGIS not just shapefiles.

Comment: The DB manager link is broken, and the PostGIS Manger link leads to a page that says this is "depracated" in favor of DB Manager (which can handle SpatiaLite and PostGIS).

Answer (score 24):

You can use the DBManager core plugin

[image]

Comment: please help me in that Query Builder question .i badly need answer for that only.........?

Comment: Is this something new? I don't see Import Layer & Export Layer Buttons in DB Manager v 0.1.20 in QGIS 1.8 on Windows Xp.

Comment: New in 2.0, well 1.9, until 2.0 is released.

Answer (score 3):

To export your vector file, with re-projection option using ogr2ogr, here is the command line:

> ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=Your_host port=your_DB_port(5432) dbname=your_DB_name password=DB_password user=DB_user" dir_to_your_Vector(.shp, .gml, .geojson...) -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco SCHEMA=your_DB_schema(public) -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=id -nln your_Output_Table_Name -s_srs EPSG:your_Source_EPSG_code -t_srs EPSG:your_Target_EPSG_code

Don't forget to check that you have permissions to connect to the hose where the postgis is and to create the database.

Answer (score 1):

Not a new answer, just an updated screen shot for Nathan W's excellent one.  The DB manager interface is a bit different now (2.18) and the options are now in menus.   The SQL window is under Database and the table related ones under table.

[image: screed shot fro QGIS 2.18]