# Exporting shapefiles from QGIS to PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile

The tutorials I've been seeing such as this one https://saarapakarinen.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/tutorial-creating-a-postgis-database-for-qgis-part-2/

They mention a SPIT plugin that I can't find anywhere even after installing the WIEN version. DB Manager doesn't quite seem to do the same thing as described in the link above

Is there some other plugin to do the job?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In 2.8 - 2.14 (Not sure about earlier versions) you can export shape files to PostGIS using the build in DB Manager.

1. Open DB Manager
   [image]
2. In the list of PostGIS databases find the one you want to export to, find the desired schema and pres the button marked with the red outline.
   [image]
3. Choose the shape file in 'input' (Has to be in your 'Layers Panel') and press 'ok'
   [image]

That's it. Your shape file is now a table in PostGIS.

EDIT
I see that this question has actually already been answered in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69053/exporting-shapefile-to-postgis-database-in-qgis?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you, I was trying that but for some reason I wasn't being able to save my shapefile on postgis. Also I saw that link but it involves other stuff while your explanation is more clear and direct

Comment: Hey Jonas, I've been trying to upload a large file (12Gb) and I tried doing what you just did but QGIS stopped responding, is it uploading or did it crash and fail?

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool bundled with PostGIS 2.2:

PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter

It allows you to import and export.

Comment: That is a fantastic program! I found it in the official Postgis for Windows bundle here: http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/

Answer (score 4):

The "SPIT" plugin is no longer bundled with QGIS, as the plugin was unmaintained and has been surpassed by DB Manager and the processing database import algorithms.

[changelog.qgis.org/](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/2.14.0/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the bin folder of Postgres,
Open CMD and

```
shp2pgsql -I  -s 4326 -g the_geom(geometry coloumn) FIlepath/filename.shp shema.tablename | psql -h localhost -d datbasename -U username
```