# Export selected PostGIS features to a new PostGIS layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, export

I am trying to export a selected set of features from a PostGIS layer into a new layer. But when I go to the context menu for the later and choose `Export -> Save Selected As ...`, there is no option for saving the selection into PostGIS. The only options are GeoPackage, Shapfiles etc:

[image]

*Is there a way to save to PostGIS without going through these other format first?*

(This is with Ubuntu 18.04, QGIS 3.6, PostgreSQL 11, PostGIS 2.5).

Answer (score 7):

You can use DB Manager for this purpose but first you need to create postgis connection to that database using QGIS. To create PostGIS connection

1. Open QGIS and right click on PostGIS icon in QGIS browser as shown
   in image below.

   [image]
2. Provide the DB connection details in the form shown below and click
       ok.

   [image]

After you create connection open DB Manager

1. In the list of PostGIS databases find the one you want to export to.
2. Find the desired schema and press import layer button as shown below.

   [image]
3. Choose the shape file in 'input' (Has to be in your 'Layers Panel')
   and press 'ok' enter, you can refer to image below

[image]

That's it. Your shape file is now a table in PostGIS.

Answer (score 2):

you can use db manager for this. 
Everything is explain in this post : 
[How to export shapefiles from QGIS to PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194714/how-to-export-shapefiles-from-qgis-to-postgis/194730)