Populate new Azure PostgreSQL DB from existing shapefile using QGIS
I have a fresh  Azure PostgreSQL DB with PostGIS Extension.  I am in QGIS and have made the connection and tested it.  It seems fine.
USING QGIS 3.34 I am using DB Manager to "Import Layer/File".  When the layer is selected, I do not see the geometry checkbox available.  When I select "OK" on the import vector layer box, I receive the error:

Error 2 Creation of data source "public"."places" failed:  ERROR:
function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer,
unknown, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
AddGeometryColumn('public','places',NULL,4326,'POINT'...
^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Can anyone suggest a better method or describe what I am doing wrong?



did you CREATE EXTENSION postgis;?  The server may have postgis installed, but you also have to create the extension in your database.

I did this but did not have the semicolon at the end.  I will try again.   I found this link.  But that seems like exactly what I am doing. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194714/exporting-shapefiles-from-qgis-to-postgis

I ran show azure.extensions; and it is not there.  I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889699/azure-postgresql-extension-postgis and the GUI installed the extension.  I followed along the excellent instruction.   I'll try again with QGIS.

I am still getting the same error.  I checked the DB with "show azure.extensions;" and postgis is showing for the DB

I think you still need to run CREATE EXTENSION postgis; in an SQL terminal connected to your db.  https://cloudydatablog.net/ms-azure-azure-database-for-postgres-flexible-server-install-postgis/

I did run CREATE EXTENSION postgis; then ran show azure.extensions; to verify.   I shut down QGIS and restarted.  IT WORKED!  Thanks for your help. @jbalk
