# QGIS Transfer Geomerty from Shapefile (loaded in QGIS) to PostgreSQL Table

Tags: qgis, geometry

I have seen a few postings relating to this question but the solutions are described with minimal detail, so I am looking for a MORE descriptive response. The solution I desire is via QGIS.

My procedure is as follows;

1. Connect to the Shapefile (source table)
2. Connect to the cloud PostgreSQL (PG) table (target table)
3. Enter a record (metadata only) in the PostgreSQL. The "geom" column is null for this record.
4. Save the edit in the PG table
5. Now open the attribute table for the PG Table and select the row
6. On the QGIS map enable the Shapefile table and query for the corresponding record and select the feature on the map which has geometry.
7. Enable the Advanced Digitizing Tools tool bar
8. Enable editing on the PG Table???
9. Select the "Add Part" button

**Steps 8 and 9 is where I am unsure what else needs to be done, as well as the remainder of the process to save the geometry in the PG Table (target).**

Comment: Are you trying to copy a Shapefile to PG, row by row, between attribute tables *manually*? If there is no really, *really* good, fundamental and existential, life-and-death deciding reason to do that, please either use one of the many tools to import arbitrary (spatial) formats into PG (e.g. ogr2ogr, shp2pgsql), or the QGIS Browser (panel) to drag'n'drop layers between locations...

Comment: In the problem definition I states I am trying to 'transfer" a geometry from one table (connected Shapefile) to another table (PostgresSQL) WITHIN QGIS.  I have read this can be done with the "Add Part" Digitizing Tool in QGIS. This is a one off exercise-- not tablewise transfer.

Comment: as long as you have PostGIS setup with a geom column you can copy features from a shapefile and paste into postgres. But Pgadmin has a import shapefile option that would avoid any corruption

Comment: DB Manager plugin has an import option https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69053/exporting-shapefile-to-postgis-database-in-qgis/69055#69055

Comment: We are running QGIS v2.18.11 - Ed o not have any of those plugins available and nor can we obtain them. I am specifically looking for the "Add Part" technique of transferring Geometry.